# Could this organism be viable?

Tags: biology, creature-design

I was wondering how the species described below could survive in tropical, subtropical, and warm temperate zones and in mountains, forests, wetlands, deserts, open plains, rainforests and coastal areas. A species I have been designing are artificially created using terrestrial endothermic mollusks. They are externally similar to humans save for some liberties such as chitin and bony plates on their chests and forearms, depending on the variant, and they are very different internally, with a less developed endoskeleton and a digestive system closely resembling an octopus'. They range from 3 meters tall (very rare, only 1 to 3 thousand worldwide) to a meter to 122 centimeters two (extremely common, 5 billion worldwide).

They would have a circulatory and respiratory system similar to that of an octopus. Their minds would also function similar to that of an octopus' except for the numerous lesser neuron clusters in the tentacles. To elaborate on the skeletal system; it consists of an endo- and exoskeleton, with the exoskeleton covering the torso and forearms and the endoskeleton making up the spinal column, limb bones, finger and toe bones and the skull. Their tendons and ligaments are very primitive, being little more that particularly fibrous muscles. Their joints would be more fluid than that of a standard human and held in place by connecting muscles and joints locks, such as in hinge joints, but they would still allow a greater range of motion. The exception is in the hands, wrists, ankles and feet where the joints are very connected in a manner similar to ours.

Their skin has a structure identical to ours with the production of hair located on the scalp, brow, eyelids and, only in some subspecies, the face. They would have a largely identical facial structure to ours, save for the bones. They have a brain case, orbital cavities, an upper jaw that is fused to the brain case and a lower jaw identical to ours. Everything from the upper teeth to the orbital cavities is occupied by muscle and their inner ears. They have a sense of smell, taste and a nose that operates similarly to a humans. They are capable of respiring through their skin. They have no external ears and instead rely on the minute vibrations in their eyes produced to trigger bones in their mid facial cavity to move and then it operates very similarly to that of a humans. Their eyes are identical to that of a cephalopod's, save for that is focuses by changing the shape of the lens, like that of a humans. Their brains operate in a mix of human and cephalopod thought patterns and structure, which are already similar. They are omnivorous.

Edit: I have fixed the formatting. Also, I realize I made a mistake regarding height. I meant 3 meters instead of 9 for the tall subspecies.

Comment: Please organize the information you've put down here. It is a huge block of text. I tried breaking it up into sections but the facts you provided are not organized as far as I can tell.

Comment: it is very hard to answer this without their evolutionary history. physically they seem like they could exist, except with the much larger height, since hominids cannot grow that large.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely such a creature would come about through natural selection - there's a reason cephalophods aren't humans shaped, or use most of the structures that humans use

Comment: @Halfthawed They are not really meant to have arisen naturally at all but rather through deliberate design.

Comment: Also, @Itmauve I have fixed the formatting, I hope.

Comment: @meaninglessname I made a mistake in the height, it has been corrected.

Comment: @AMorningstar You say 'descended from terrestrial endothermic mollusks'. If these are genetically engineered, you should specify that in the question.

Comment: @Halfthawed, you are correct. I apologise.

Comment: Your question contains a very high number of very specific details, writing an answer that comments on even most of those would be a lot of work (especially as a lot of your point are quite disorganized). I'd recommend you to reorganize the description of your species into more coherent sections and highlight those aspects that you specifically want feedback on.

Comment: An additional thing that you might want to expand on is the knowledge / technology level of whoever artificially designed this species in-universe - with current day genetic engineering the simple fact of designed a species is very far fetched, but this can of course go up to 'technology indistinguishable from magic' levels of possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more context it is difficult to give an appropriate answer. Also I suggest making your design more streamlined, for example describing them as terrestrial humanoid octopuses gives your readers a lot of reference from the natural world.

First there are already octopuses with bones and even some that grow shells to protect their eggs. So yes, you can give them a skeleton and outer shell for support and protection.

Second you do not need human skin and hair. They live in a humid tropical environment correct? Then a mollusks slimy skin is better as it absorbs moisture and allows them to breath through their skin better like amphibians. Hair is meant to keep the head warm but since they live in warm places that seems unnecessary.

You seem to want to give them as much of a human appearance as possible while having their internal structure be completely different. But if I were you I'd add extra arms, camouflaging skin and maybe an ink pouch. After all if they were designed why limit oneself to the fragile human form? Their arms can have some independence because of their decentralized nervous system and their skins color changing can be used for communication, like writing on their body instead of talking. The ink pouch is optional, as it can also be used for writing.